# Why can't Ubuntu recognize my parititions?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 as a dual-boot with Windows 8.1 on a Toshiba Satellite p55-A5200.

I downloaded it and installed the boot-helper, because my startup showed no menus. It then showed a choice between Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu on startup, so I chose to try out Ubuntu then install.

In trying to install Ubuntu, it cannot find any other OS even though I have turned off safe boot in Windows. The computer recognizes that the partitions are there, but Ubuntu does not. The same happened with 12.04.

[image: installer/parted screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The screen shot you posted shows it recognizes the partitions just fine; what it seems to have trouble with is the filesystem in the 4th partition.  There seems to be something wrong with it, so run chkdsk /f on it from Windows.  Also make sure you have disabled the "fast boot" option in Windows, which hibernates the computer instead of shutting down, and that prevents safely accessing the partition from another OS.

`parted`'s resize command only works on fat and hfs.

Answer (score 0):

Like @psusi said,Ubuntu fails to recognize the partition.This is because your Windows OS isn't shutdown properly.You can check it with running the below commands on terminal,

```
sudo mkdir /media/os
sudo mount /dev/sda4 /media/os
```

The output of the above command will be like,

```
The NTFS partition is hibernated. Please resume and shutdown Windows properly.
```

For this you have to follow the below steps,

- Shutdown the Ubuntu OS and then remove the Ubuntu live disk.
- Boot into Windows and make a **Restart**(not shutdown).
- Now it automatically boot into Windows.Now Shutdown your Windows PC.(Between these operations,don't try to view the files in C or D like drives).
- In the shudown state,insert your Ubuntu installation disk and then boot from it.Now your Ubuntu installer will recognize that partition.And you can make changes on it.